# In Slurm, how to submit multiple experimental runs in a batch, and excute them consecutively one-by-one?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cluster-computing, slurm, experimental-design

**Submitting jobs on a gpu cluster managed by Slurm.**

I am doing some experiments and as you know we have to tune the parameters, which means I need to run several similar scripts with different hyperparameters. So I wrote multiple bash scripts (say, named *training_n.sh*) for executing, in each script it's like:

```
# training_n.sh
    
srun [command with specific model/training hyperparameters]
```

Then I use `sbatch` to execute these scripts, in the `sbatch` script it's like:

```
# sbatch script

bash training_1.sh
bash training_2.sh
...
bash training_n.sh
```

If I have a list of "srun"s in my "sbatch" script as shown above, how are they arranged in the queue (assuming I run on a single partition)? Are all these "srun"s seen as a single job or they are seen as separate jobs?

In other words, are they consecutively queued in the "squeue" list and will be executed consecutively? Or by contrast, other users' jobs will queue exactly behind the "srun" I am running and the remaining "srun"s can only be executed after these users' jobs are completed?

Additionally, **any better ideas** to submit a batch of experiment scripts on a publically used cluster? **Since many people are using it, I want to complete all my designed experiments consecutively once it's my turn**, instead of finishing one "srun" and waiting for other users to complete to start my next one.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a list of "srun"s in my "sbatch" script as shown above, how are they arranged in the queue (assuming I run on a single partition)? Are all these "srun"s seen as a single job or they are seen as separate jobs?
> In other words, are they consecutively queued in the "squeue" list and will be executed consecutively? Or by contrast, other users' jobs will queue exactly behind the "srun" I am running and the remaining "srun"s can only be executed after these users' jobs are completed?

If you submit all these single `srun` scripts/commands in a single `sbatch` script, you will only get one job. The reason for this is that `srun` works differently inside a job allocation then outside. If you run `srun` inside a job allocation (e.g. in an sbatch script), it will **not** create a new job, but just create a job step. So in your case, you will have a single job with *n* job steps, that will run consecutively in your allocation.

> Additionally, any better ideas to submit a batch of experiment scripts on a publically used cluster?

If these runs are completely independent, you should use a [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_array), with size *n*. This way you can create *n* jobs that can run whenever there are resources available.

> Since many people are using it, I want to complete all my designed experiments consecutively once it's my turn, instead of finishing one "srun" and waiting for other users to complete to start my next one.

That might not be a good idea. If these jobs are independent, you can rather submit them as an array. This way, they could take advantage of backfill scheduling and might run more quickly. You likely don't gain anything by putting them into a large job.

Comment: I think "putting them into a large job" (put multiple sruns in an sbatch script) will make it impossible for other people to insert in my job array, and thus I can complete all my experiments at a time without waiting. Is that true? Does the sbatch in slurm work like this?

Comment: Yes and no. You are right in that other people will not go in between your calculations, if you pack them all into one job. But on the other hand, if you have one huge job, the waiting time in the queue until it starts will most likely be significantly longer, whereas with many small jobs, they can usually start quite quickly. But this also depends on how Slurm on your cluster is configures. Maybe ask your sysadmin, what they prefer.